# How to load a particular php file by id on live to show on a hover div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I make a update side bar which load news after 10 sec interval.

Now I want, when I hover on a signal news of side bar Its show full story in a side div and this side div collect data from a particular php file like news.php?id=".$id."

my hover div work well and show a div but I cannot understand how to load live full story here by id

Clear again; How to load a particular php file by id on live to show on a hover div

I want to do similar like facebook right side bar ticker. which show full story on hover a particular post.

my js

```
$(".upbox1").mouseover(function() {
  var pos = $(this).position();
  var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $("#menu").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: pos.top + "px",
        left: (pos.right + width) + "px"
    }).fadeIn("slow");
});
  $("#menu").mouseout(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeOut("slow");
  });
  $("body").click(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

Below is my hover div.

```
echo'<div class="popup" id="menu">';
  // Full story will goes here from news.php?id=xxxxx
echo'</div>';
```

Comment: If you want to load data from a post by hover, you must call the php file with Ajax. $.ajax() can be what are you looking for

Comment: Yes. I think about it but can't understand how to call ajax live on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$(".upbox1").mouseover(function() {
 $.get("news.php?id=" + id, function(data) {
  $('#menu').empty().html(data);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank u sir. I m trying. . .

Comment: How to make the hover more smooth like facebook? can u give me any Idea.

Comment: That's the topic of another discussion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".upbox1").mouseover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-href"); //for example, put a data-href attr in your class with the id of the post
    $.get("php_file.php?id="+id, function(data) {
        //data is what php_file will return
        $(".menu").html(data); //this inserts into the class menu the data that the php file gave you
    });
});
```

In the php file, use a query to database and retrieve the info. and echo all the data you want, for example:

```
$myData = "<div>".$data['title']."</div>";
$myData .= "<div>".$data['description']."</div>";
echo $myData;
```

Comment: Thank u sir. Its working. But I followed Mave answer first. so I just give u a up vote.